# How to align plotly_chart to page center using html in streamlit

Tags: python, html, streamlit

[image]

```py
def plot_open_close_chart(dataframe: pd.DataFrame, name: str, start_date: int, end_date: int) -> stl.plotly_chart:
    fig = dataframe.iplot(y="Open",
             secondary_y="Close",
             secondary_y_title="Close Price ($)",
             xTitle="Date", yTitle="Open Price ($)",
             title=f'''Open and Close Price  of {name} From {start_date} To {end_date}''', asFigure=True)
    stl.plotly_chart(fig)
    get_record_low_and_high(dataframe, dataframe.Close)
```

I tried to set the chart to page center just like the "**Record Low**" below the chart is set using **html** but it does seem to work with the chart. It will be a pleasure if anyone can help fix this. I also tried writing **fig** in html and but it shows nothing in page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `stl.plotly_chart(fig)` for `stl.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width = True)`. This won't center align the chart, but once you close the `sidebar` the chart will fill the entire width of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to `stl.columns` and create three columns (left, middle, right) where you only use the middle one:

```
left, middle, right = stl.columns((2, 5, 2))
with middle:
    plot_open_close_chart()
```

Comment: Hi arnaud. thanks for your responds, I have used such approach but then when I collapse the apps sidebar it affects the alignment of the chart but not the text after the chart.